# Run a Node Script before running React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I tried adding `node seedApp.ts` in here before it tries to run my React app but I get `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

```
"web-dev-test-manually": "NODE_ENV=localApp node seedApp.ts && yarn lint && yarn copyData && yarn compile-server && yarn start-static-server & node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server -d --watch",
```

**seedApp.ts**

```
import { setupDatabase } from '../Database/SeedApp';

(async () => {
    await setupDatabase(['appdev/seed.companies.sql', 'appdev/seed.crafters.sql']);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `node seedApp.ts` before your start script in `package.json`
For example, something like this should work.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node start.js && react-scripts start"
}
```

Comment: @sebtheiler answer is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: that is nothing different than what I already tried

Answer (score -1):

Try using `require` instead of `import`:

```js
const { setupDatabase } = require('../Database/SeedApp');

(async () => {
    await setupDatabase(['appdev/seed.companies.sql', 'appdev/seed.crafters.sql']);
})();
```